# Hide/Unhide a ribbon button in Dynamics CRM 2015 by Javascript

Tags: dynamics-crm-2015

I need your help: How I can Hide/Unhide a ribbon button in Dynamics CRM 2015 by Javascript?

Thank you in advance !!

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by customizing Ribbon XML, using [Ribbon Work Bench](https://ribbonworkbench.uservoice.com/knowledgebase/articles/71374-1-getting-started-with-the-ribbon-workbench) makes it easier than doing a manual edit. You would need to use the "Enable Rule" portion of the customization and call your JavaScript function, returning true/false would show/hide the button. If you simply need to hide it and not toggle the display, you could use the same tool to hide the button by simply selecting the button and hiding it using context menu options.